# R: for i in seq(nrow(dataframe)) doesn't evaluate the last row correctly

Tags: regex, r, for-loop

I have the following `data frame` (urlsRaw):

```
> View(urlsRaw)
    row.names   links                 urls
1   1           Menü                  javascript:void(0);
2   2           Link1                 /story/1
3   3           Home                  http://www.domain.com
4   4           CDN Google            //cdn.google.com
... ...         ...                   ...
48  54          Share in Facebook     https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=
49  55          Share in Twitter      https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=
```

With the following script I want to delete all rows where the value in the column urls doesn't belong to an analysed domain (f.i. `page <- "http://www.domain.com"`) or aren't relative paths to this domain (note the regex `^[/][^/]` to prevent "protocol relative" URIs like *//cdn.google.com* beign considered Urls to be keep.

```
# Loop over each row and if URL not valid (starts with "/" or "page variable") delete row
for(i in seq(nrow(urlsRaw))) {
  if(grepl(sprintf("^[/][^/]|^(%s)", page), urlsRaw$urls[i]) == FALSE) {
    urlsRaw <- urlsRaw[-i, ]
  }
}
```

Everything works fine, but the last observation in `data.frame urlsRaw` isn't beign evaluated correctly as `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=` clearly dosn't pass the `grepl` check and is not beign deleted. I am sure that the regex is correct (could be possibly optimized) because if I run the for statement again, the row is correctly deleted.

Therefore, I assume that something is happening with the `for` if rows are beign deleted in the middle of the loop. Can someone give me a tip of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: anytime your if evaluates to true, you make the data frame smaller but you are still indexing over the original size. why not just do `urlsRaw[grepl(sprintf("^[/][^/]|^(%s)", page), urlsRaw$urls), ]`? you dont need a loop

Comment: @rawr so easy and clean that I am ashamed :) Thx. I believe that I have to stop thinking like I am programming in JavaScript. DO you mind writing the comment as answer to accept it?